# How to transition from nested route into index route in Emberjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

My Routes

```
NoteApp.Router.reopen
    location: 'history'
    rootURL: '/'

NoteApp.Router.map ->
   @resource 'notes', path: "/", ->
       @route 'new', path: "/new"

NoteApp.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    model: ()->
        return @store.find('note')

NoteApp.NotesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    renderTemplate: (controller, model) ->
        @render 'notes/new', into: "application"
```

My NotesNewController is:

```
NoteApp.NotesNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
    actions:
        createNote: ->
            title = @get('newTitle')
            note = @store.createRecord('note',
                title: title
            )

            note.save()
            @set('newTitle', '')
            @transitionToRoute('notes')
```

**First problem**: I can't use browser back button after navigate to /new route

**Second problem**: `@transitionToRoute('notes')` not working. Simply render blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the notes template when you manually render into the application outlet.  This is where all of your problems are coming from.

If you want the url `/notes` to show something, then not be visible when you are on `/notes/new` you should add that to your `notes/index` template.

So in a nutshell, I'm suggesting these things.

#### Comment this out

```
NoteApp.NotesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    //renderTemplate: (controller, model) ->
        //@render 'notes/new', into: "application"
```

#### Move notes template to notes/index

#### Make sure your notes template has `{{outlet}}` in it

Comment: I want to notes.new template rendering into own page. I can use
`@resource('new_note')`, but in my opinion it's not mental approach.